# Can't get time right with arduino?

Tags: arduino, display, arduino-ide, led

I have a small 7 segment led display and I wondered if I could get it to show me the last digit of the minute. Downloaded the Time library for Arduino and I tried several methods, with switch case and if else if, but all give the same result, the LED display shows only 0... Could you pinpoint what I did wrong?

```
#include <Time.h>
#include <TimeLib.h>

int led1=2;
int led2=3;
int led3=4;
int led4=5;
int led5=6;
int led6=7;
int led7=8;
int led8=9;

void setup() {

  pinMode(led1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led3,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led4,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led5,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led6,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led7,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led8,OUTPUT);

}

void loop(){
  time_t t=minute();
  int digit1=t%10;


  if(digit1==1){
    digitalWrite(led5, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);
    }else if(digit1==2)

    {
    digitalWrite(led6, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led5, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led4, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
    } else if(digit1==3)

    {
    digitalWrite(led4, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led6, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led5, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
    }else if(digit1==4)

    {
    digitalWrite(led4, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led7, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led5, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);
    }else if(digit1==5)

    {
    digitalWrite(led6, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led7, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led4, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
    }else if(digit1==6)

    {
    digitalWrite(led6, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led7, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led4, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);
    }else if(digit1==7)

    {
    digitalWrite(led5, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led6, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);
    }else if(digit1==8)

    {
    digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led4, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led5, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led6, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led7, HIGH);
    }else if(digit1==9)

    {
    digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led4, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led5, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led6, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led7, HIGH);
    }else if(digit1==0)

    {
    digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led5, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led6, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led7, HIGH);
    }





}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't added low conditions hence when the pin is going high it is remaining high. Also, I have checked and I think that your wiring is not correct. I'm posting complete code below and connections accordingly.

[image: CONNECTIONS FOR 7 SEG]

```
#include <Time.h>
#include <TimeLib.h>

int a  = 2;
int b  = 3;
int c  = 4;
int d  = 5;
int e  = 6;
int f  = 7;
int g  = 8;
int dp = 9;

void setup() {
    pinMode(led1,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(led2,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(led3,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(led4,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(led5,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(led6,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(led7,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(led8,OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){
    time_t t=minute();
    int digit1=t%10;


    if(digit1==0) {
        digitalWrite(a, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(c, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(d, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(e, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(f, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(g, LOW);
        digitalWrite(dp, LOW);   
    }

    else if(digit1==1) {
        digitalWrite(a, LOW);
        digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(c, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(d, LOW);
        digitalWrite(e, LOW);
        digitalWrite(f, LOW);
        digitalWrite(g, LOW);
        digitalWrite(dp, LOW);   
    }

    else if(digit1==2) {
        digitalWrite(a, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(c, LOW);
        digitalWrite(d, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(e, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(f, LOW);
        digitalWrite(g, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(dp, LOW);   
    }

    else if(digit1==3) {
        digitalWrite(a, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(c, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(d, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(e, LOW);
        digitalWrite(f, LOW);
        digitalWrite(g, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(dp, LOW);   
    }

    else if(digit1==4) {
        digitalWrite(a, LOW);
        digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(c, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(d, LOW);
        digitalWrite(e, LOW);
        digitalWrite(f, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(g, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(dp, LOW);   
    }

    else if(digit1==5) {
        digitalWrite(a, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(b, LOW);
        digitalWrite(c, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(d, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(e, LOW);
        digitalWrite(f, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(g, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(dp, LOW);   
    }

    else if(digit1==6) {
        digitalWrite(a, LOW);
        digitalWrite(b, LOW);
        digitalWrite(c, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(d, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(e, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(f, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(g, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(dp, LOW);   
    }

    else if(digit1==7) {
        digitalWrite(a, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(c, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(d, LOW);
        digitalWrite(e, LOW);
        digitalWrite(f, LOW);
        digitalWrite(g, LOW);
        digitalWrite(dp, LOW);   
    }

    else if(digit1==8) {
        digitalWrite(a, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(c, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(d, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(e, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(f, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(g, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(dp, LOW);   
    }

    else if(digit1==9) {
        digitalWrite(a, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(c, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(d, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(e, LOW);
        digitalWrite(f, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(g, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(dp, LOW);   
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried your method to rewire and pull the respective LEDs LOW but to no avail. The problem is the value that 't' is assigned. I commented out the switch case/if else if part and tried to print the value on the serial monitor, which is still 0 all the time. I will add a photo of the serial monitor as well.

Comment: yes, the display is common cathode, the display is actually a 4-digit display, with a cathode for each digit and then an anode for each led segment(http://raspi.tv/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/7seg-pinout-annotated_1500.jpg). But the problem is not with the display, is with the time variable t, and what it returns...

Comment: Im getting correct output with above program. To view the change you have to wait for one minute then and then you'll able to see the change from 0 to 1. I tried using `time_t t=second();` and got output on every second.

Comment: well yes, I do this and it starts from 0 and goes on steadily, and the display works just fine with the minute function as well, but I what I was thinking when I heard of this time library is that it could get the time from the device you connected it to(laptop in my case) and store it, for example store 11:23(the time in my region) and then you could go ahead and do whatever you wanted w/ it (https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/Time)

Comment: If getting current time from laptop is ur moto then it will be another question. I ll happy to help in that too. As the problem is solved, please accept the answer and upvote. Cheers.

Comment: I would if I could :/, anyway thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

You never write any of the pins to go low. When the next minute hits, the proper LEDS are probably turning on, but the old ones don't go off, so you don't see any change.

To avoid turning all the LEDS off and on again every cycle, I would store the last known digit and at each loop iteration, see if the digit has changed. If it has, turn off all of the lights and then run the code you posted here.

Comment: I have tried your method but to no avail. The problem is the value that 't' is assigned. I commented out the switch case/if else if part and tried to print the value on the serial monitor, which is still 0 all the time. I will add a photo of the serial monitor as well.